# Create a column from another column information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
a b      
1 black 
2 red   
3 black
4 blue
5 blue
```

How can get this dataframe:

```
a   bleu black red   
1   0     1     0
2   0     0     1 
3   0     1     0
4   1     0     0 
5   1     0     0
```

Comment: explore `pandas.get_dummies`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html